# Which plug-ins for SonarQube, Jenkins, BitBucket?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, bitbucket

I'm trying to set up a CI environment at my company, and they're using **BitBucket** for SCM, **Jenkins** and **Maven** for build, and **SonarQube** for static code evaluation.  The problem I've encountered is one of "too many plugins".  There are numerous plugins in this area and it would take me forever to test each combination to see what works.

Is there anyone out there that has a **working setup** with these three components?  My end objective is to have SonarQube evaluate **pull requests**, and have those results available to the code reviewer when (s)he looks at the request.

Comment: Bitbucket Server or Bitbucket Cloud?

Comment: Bitbucket Server - it's local Jim.

Answer (score 0):

The following plugins are great to start:

```
Bitbucket => Parameterized Builds for Jenkins, Sonar for Bitbucket Server

Jenkins   => Bitbucket Server Notifier

SonarQube => SonarQube Scanner
```

Comment: Did it help you as expected?